# Retrieve different density pixels images from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a `listview` that retrives images from [parse.com](http://parse.com). But in [parse.com](http://parse.com) I can upload only one density pixel image which is retrieved. How I support multiple devices with different densities like `xhdpi,xhdpi,xxxhpi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have listview,so you have adapter for the listview. So you can layout view for the adapter like below
You define the Imageview width and height in a certain number.And the and the scaleType is fitxy, So all  the image you download will display as you defined size.

```
<ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>
```

Comment: But what about the quality of the images. It will get a bit pixelated in phones with high pixel density

Comment: of course , if the image is in low resolution and you display it in high dpi screen , it will be bad. So it will be if you put low resolution in the  hdpi folder and show it in high dpi screen. So in my opinion, you should upload high quality image so it will be good in any density

Comment: But even the size of images matter because I have a lot of images to display

Comment: I hope i can explain it clearly ,because my english is bad :-D. Now you get a lot of images to display and are they in same resolution? If all images are in same resolution. So the solution is ok. If then images in different resolution , so it depends on how you want it to display. For example. you get two Image, one is 1080p and one is 480p. So if you want to show them in same size, it will cause bad quality.if you want to show good quality, so change the up code layout_width and layout_height to warp_content.

Comment: Yeah got it. And you English is not bad . I understand what you say. That's enough to solve my problem. Thanks